# Strange behavior of javascript events after pressing two keys at the same time

Tags: javascript, events

I'm coding a little javascript app and I need to control screen events (images appearance). For example if image_1 appear on the screem I need to press one key (for example right arrow) and if image_2 appear a I need to press another key (for instance left arrow). If both of them appear at the same time I need to press both keys.

The problem is that if I press both keys at the same time, then no more key events are launched, I mean when next image appear I press a key but there is not javascript event.

I make the code simple for you to try:

```
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test1</title>
    <script>

    function addE () {
        if (document.addEventListener)  {// standard W3C DO
                document.addEventListener("keydown",test1,false);
        }
    }

    // ejemplo equivalente para quitar el evento
    function removeE () {
        if (document.removeEventListener)  {// standard W3C DOM
                document.removeEventListener("keydown",test1,false);
         }
    }


    function test1 (e) {
        alert('test');
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 39: 
              alert(e.keyCode);
            break;
            case 37:  
              alert(e.keyCode);
            break;
            default:
              alert(e.keyCode);
        }
    }


    window.onload = function() {
        addE();
        alert('Listener added');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you can see if you press any key it will appear an alert to indicate you are in "test1" and the KeyCode. If you press two at the same time you get: test - test - keycode (1) -keycode (2) and after that you can press any of the keys and you get nothing

Comment: I wouldn't be using alerts to test this...
pressing 2 keys at the same time wouldn't do anything, since only one of them (the 1st key to get read by the system) would trigger the alert, thus making any code afterwards be null (Alerts basically stop anything from happening), switch to console.logs to test this.

Comment: I agree, If you need to use a poor-man's debugging tool, use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for advice, I tried using console.log() and every event is recognize. So you think my problem was to use alert and ther is no code problem? I'm goingto try right now in the real app and I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Alert()  never again ; ) I tried with console.log() and i saw that my code is ok. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gonçalo Vieira and Andy E suggested me, the problem was no my code but the debugging alert I was using. When a changed to a better debuggin solution, console.log(), everything worked ok